# Replace one char in a string using its index in matlab

Tags: regex, xml, string, matlab, char

I have generated an .xml file from Matlab, and I cannot open it in a browser. The reason for this is that when the .xml file is created, it has some 'smaller than' or 'greater than' operators. For example, one generated .xml file is:

```
<test Name='blabla' User='User1' Value='<2'>
```

Now, how can I change this symbol '<' to 'smaller than' but only at the position where it stands before the number 2? I tried using the regular expression to find the index:

```
splitStr = regexp(xmlString,'<\d')
```

With this one I only get the index, but I don't know how to replace it. Using regexprep, replaces every '<' in the string, including the one in the beginning of the string, and then the xml will not open in a browser for sure.

Or if there is any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated: replace 1 character by multiple:

Suppose you have `x = 'a<bc'` and want to replace the second character by ' less than '

You could do it like so:

```
[x(1:1) ' less than ' x(3:end)]
```

It will give

```
a less than bc
```

From here it should be straightforward to create a general solution.

---

If you have the index and want to replace a character it is simple, let us suppose the index is 2:

```
x = 'abcd'
x(2) = 'z'
```

will yield

```
'azcd'
```

Comment: that works if the character that you want to replace it with is the same line, like in your case you just replace 'b' with 'z'. If I try x(31) = ' less than ', it gives an error: In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B
must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about MatLab syntax for Regex, but with something like

```
(?<=['"])([^'"]*?)<([^'"]*?)(?=['"])
```

https://regex101.com/r/oK9wX2/2

You could catch every `<` inside quotes and replace it with `&lt;` - same thing for `>` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

## The fix

The exact thing you ask is easily achieved with string replace:

```
s = "<test Name='blabla' User='User1' Value='<2'>"
strrep(s,'<2','less than 2')
```

For more complicated patterns you can of course use `regexrep` instead.

## The solution

However, you mention:

> I have generated an .xml file from Matlab

In fact, a `<` should not be in xml, so I would say you have generated a file that is similar to xml. From here it is easy to see that the real solution would be to deal with special characters during the files creation!